# Joomla! 3.8 - How to hide Publishing Tab in front end

Tags: overrides, form, front-end

My registered users can log in to see, create and edit only their own articles. This works fine. However, when a user creates or edits an article, the "*Publishing*" tab appears at the top with "*Content*" and "*Language*".

I do NOT want the "*Publishing*" tab to be seen at all.

Iv hunted around for this but it seems that all of the help available is for earlier versions of Joomla, and they do not work.

Iv been into the `Global Configuration->Articles->Editing Layout` Panel and everything is set to "*Hide*", but the Publishing Tab is still visible. Limited, but still visible.

Following some advice I have over-ridden `com-content->form` but I cant find the code in there to hide this tab and the advice appears to have been for an earlier version of Joomla!.

Any help would be much appreciated.

---

UPDATE: Over-riding the `com-content->form` has offered possibilities however removing the code that apparently houses the Publishing tab, while removing the tab, prevents users from saving new articles because the category needs to be set (Not sure why - the default is Uncategorised and not setting it works fine when the Publishing tab is visible).

Still a little lost with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, a solution has been found.

It appears that somewhere in the back end a new article requires the category to be set. It also appears that its a lot easier to pick and choose what items to see in the Publishing tab.

Note that everything is on the publishing tab turned off in the global configuration. This leaves the publishing tab still visible. I *thought* that I wanted to remove the tab entirely, but since I would like my users to be able to delete their own articles, this is not the case.

To get things to fit I have over-ridden the `com-content->form` and edited the edit.php file. Removing this line:

```
<?php echo $this->form->renderField('access'); ?>
```

has left me with a Publishing tab where each user can set their tags and their categories, and publish/trash etc, but cannot change the access level, which was my main concern originally.

Looking further at the same file it would appear that other sections of the Publishing tab could be removed or edited if need be.

Anyway, that's my solution. I hope posting an answer myself is not considered bad form.

Comment: Welcome to Joomla SO. Noghing bad with answering your own question but you should select your own answer as correct to "close" this question.

Answer (score 2):

Apart of customizing the Article Edit Form - you could consider using 3rd party extensions.

There are 2 major types/categories of extensions that would be suitable for this:

1. Front-end article management
2. CCK integration

### 1. Front-end article management

Front-end article management extensions are designed to offer front-end authoring/moderation capabilities to Joomla.

JED categories:

- https://extensions.joomla.org/tags/content-submission/
- https://extensions.joomla.org/tags/authoring-content/

Some extensions:

- There is a promising newcomer in this category made by the well-know StackIdeas. The extension is called [**easyArticles**](https://stackideas.com/easyarticles) and you can test it online [**here**](https://stackideas.com/demo).
- https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/article-factory-manager/
- https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/form2content-lite/
- https://www.joomlatools.com/extensions/textman/

### 2. CCKs Integration

Briefly, using a CCK you can create your own content-kit/content-workflow. There are CCKs that can be integrated with Joomla articles and allow you to create your own forms.

- https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/form2content-lite/
- [Fabrik](http://fabrikar.com/)
- [Seblod](https://www.seblod.com)

Comment: Thanks for the links, but Id rather not install an extension for something that I consider fairly small - just seems a bit overkill since it was really only down to editing a single file.